# Encoding problems with GIT output containing Scandinavian characters

Tags: c#, git, encoding, utf-8

I'm reading Git log output with C# program and parsing a report from it. Basically I run a command

```
git log --name-status --pretty=fuller --after="2016-08-14" -before="2016-11-03"
```

using following code.

```
// create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
// and "/c " as the parameters.
// Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command  that follows,
// and then exit.
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo gitInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
gitInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
gitInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
gitInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
gitInfo.FileName = GIT_installed_directory + @"\bin\git.exe";

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
gitInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
gitInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
gitInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
gitInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process GitProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
gitInfo.Arguments = GIT_command; // such as "fetch orign"
gitInfo.WorkingDirectory = GIT_Repository_Path;
GitProcess.StartInfo = gitInfo;
GitProcess.Start();
// Get the output into a string
string result = GitProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
result = result + GitProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

GitProcess.WaitForExit();
GitProcess.Close();
```

The result read from Git is obtained as string. Originally without any encoding the output from Git showed all Scandinavian characters in a funny way.

E.g. "KÃ¤ytettÃ¤vyys" ("Käytettävyys")

After I added encoding to UTF8

```
gitInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

the comments given in Git commit get the correct encoding but Scandinavian characters in filenames are converted to escape characters.

See example:
This is straight from the Git cmd console.

```
D:\>git log --name-status --pretty=fuller --after="2016-08-14" --before="2016-11-07"
commit 07754d5dd6b0f105233e73068a636c59b875b5f6
Author:     xxxxxxxx
AuthorDate: Fri Nov 4 13:27:57 2016 +0200
Commit:     xxxxxxxx
CommitDate: Fri Nov 4 13:27:59 2016 +0200

Kosmeettinen muutos

M       xxxxxxxxxx/Pelkkää KÖKKÖÄ.mrx
M       xxxxxxxxxx/Pelkkää KÖKKÖÄ.rpx

commit 28713f66ad16231315e2cf5318e4e2b3815305eb
Author:     xxxxxxxxxx
AuthorDate: Fri Nov 4 13:24:48 2016 +0200
Commit:     xxxxxxxxxx
CommitDate: Fri Nov 4 13:24:51 2016 +0200

Lisätty gittiin ääkkösten ja öökkästen testaamista varten

A       xxxxxxxxxx/Some file.mrx
A       xxxxxxxxxx/Some file.rpx
A       xxxxxxxxxx/Pelkkää KÖKKÖÄ.mrx
A       xxxxxxxxxx/Pelkkää KÖKKÖÄ.rpx

commit 6276b2ef46c7d6ff737a65583c4afe6b02a01bb4
```

This is the same output in my C# program:

```
commit 07754d5dd6b0f105233e73068a636c59b875b5f6
Author:     xxxxxxxx
AuthorDate: Fri Nov 4 13:27:57 2016 +0200
Commit:     xxxxxxxx
CommitDate: Fri Nov 4 13:27:59 2016 +0200

Kosmeettinen muutos

M   "xxxxxxxx/Pelkk\303\244\303\244 K\303\226KK\303\226\303\204.mrx"
M   "xxxxxxxx/Pelkk\303\244\303\244 K\303\226KK\303\226\303\204.rpx"

commit 28713f66ad16231315e2cf5318e4e2b3815305eb
Author:     xxxxxxxx
AuthorDate: Fri Nov 4 13:24:48 2016 +0200
Commit:     xxxxxxxx
CommitDate: Fri Nov 4 13:24:51 2016 +0200

Lisätty gittiin ääkkösten ja öökkästen testaamista varten

A   xxxxxxxxxx/Some file.mrx
A   xxxxxxxxxx/Some file.mrx
A   "xxxxxxxx/Pelkk\303\244\303\244 K\303\226KK\303\226\303\204.mrx"
A   "xxxxxxxx/Pelkk\303\244\303\244 K\303\226KK\303\226\303\204.rpx"

commit 6276b2ef46c7d6ff737a65583c4afe6b02a01bb4
```

What kind of additional conversions should I do to get also the file names right?

Comment: Git itself is (intended to be) encoding-agnostic. If you put UTF-8 in, it sends UTF-8 back out. If you put UTF-16-LE in, it sends that back. If you put in arbitrary byte codes, it sends those back. See http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html as well. For *paths*, it's not Git, but rather your OS, that enforces constraints (e.g., MacOS is picky about combining codes). Your C# interface may also be doing its own things—I have not used C# (and avoid Windows in general) so cannot speak to that side of the problem.

Comment: RTM: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show/1.8.2.2 :) (especially at the bottom of that page, the "Discussion" section)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know GIT uses `ErrorOutput`, so:

`gitInfo.Standard**Error**Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is ancient but didn't find too many answers googling.

I tested by saving the file in question with the Save As pulldown and choosing the encoding (Advanced Save Options). Switching from 1252 to 65001 (UTF-8) made things look better in Git. And yes, I know there are several other possibilities (highest numbered codepage I've used in my life just happened to work well).

Comment: Thanks @Peter Bäckgren! I don't even remember anymore how I solved this, or did I solve it at all.